# Remove/Hide Android 5.0 Status Bar

Tags: android, status, android-notification-bar

I need to permanent remove the Android 5.0 Status Bar (top one), does anyone knows how to do it?

I have hidden, but if the user swipes down it show up, I do not want this to happen.
On Android 4.4 I was able to do it, but now on Android 5.0 it does not work...

Thanks,

JS

Comment: julio try my answer

Answer (score 3):

Well try this

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
 int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
 decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IMMERSIVE_STICKY` Flag it will show the status bar for a sec then automatically hide it.
[**Android Docs.**](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#sticky)

You dont have to do anything just overide the `onWindowFocusChanged()` below method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```